# [ C# ]xna to monogame

Tags: xna, java, monogame

I'm thinking of going back to xna and c# because I have used java 2d, slick 2d and some other libraries. I started off with xna and c# but ignored it for java. I'm thinking of going back, but I see xna isn't being developed anymore. I read there is away to convert it to monogame but seems very complicated. XNA look fairly easy, yet I havn't toyed with monogame yet. So what I want to know , is monogame related to xna or close in coding? Would it be easy to understand if you're good with xna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've converted a few XNA projects to Monogame, with great success.  The only major issue I have had,  is converting Shaders.  If you are not dealing with shaders, there shouldn't be much problems.   Most likely, you will just have to point to the Monogame assemblies, and it will all work.

I think Monogame is a very good option for game developers.

If you have any specific concerns, ask them.  I'll try my best to answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. How long do you think it would take to convert to monogame? Also should I write my code in xna and just conver it?

Comment: It shouldn't take long. Think of XNA as a framework. What people call "XNA" is really "Microsoft XNA." Monogame is really "an open-source implementation of XNA." They're very similar.

Comment: @Mr.CodeIt depends on your project.  Some projects, you only have to point to the monogame libs, and everything works out of the box.

Comment: @Jon so I shouldn't really worry about xna. Learning monogame would probably be easier

Comment: @Mr.CodeIt Some people actually write everything in XNA, and then port it to Monogame after.  I'll have to admit, the original setup for Monogame can be problematic, but once you are up and running you should be golden.  One thing to keep in mind, is that the Monogame framework does not have a content pipeline, so you still need XNA to convert your content files into xbe.

Comment: @Jon I'm getting an error in xna saying another process is using my application. This only happens when I change the color of a Texture2D. If I change it back to white it still gets an error

Comment: @Jon  Warning 1 Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\WindowsGame1.exe" to "bin\x86\Debug\WindowsGame1.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\x86\Debug\WindowsGame1.exe' because it is being used by another process. WindowsGame1

Comment: @Mr.CodeIt That is strange.  Restart visual studio.